# What kind of unit of measurement for scale does SQL Server 2012 Spatial use?

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, spatial-database, measurements

What kind of unit of measurement for scale does SQL Server 2012 Spatial use?

Comment: As ratios of two lengths, scales are inherently unit free. Some *maps* describe their scales as ratios of lengths in different units (such as feet or miles per inch)--and when they do, they are usually clear about what lengths are involved.

Comment: If I have SRID 0, the unit will be free of measurement, but how will it measure I have coordinate (0,0) to (0,5), does it calculate by pixel, raster or something?

Comment: As whuber pointed out, the distance between (0,0) and (0,5) is 5. It isn't 5 of any particular thing, its just 5.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @whuber:

> As ratios of two lengths, scales are inherently unit free. Some maps
>   describe their scales as ratios of lengths in different units (such as
>   feet or miles per inch)--and when they do, they are usually clear
>   about what lengths are involved.

In other words, the term "unit of measurement for scale" does not make sense to use.